# Python how to type anotate a method that returns self?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.9

Suppose I have a class that implements method chaining:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class M:
    def set_width(self, width: int)->M:
        self.width = width
        return self

    def set_height(self, height: int)->M:
        self.height = height
        return self
```

I could use it like this:

```
box = M().set_width(5).set_height(10)
```

This works, but if I have a subclass M3D:

```
class M3D(M):
    def set_depth(self, depth: int) -> M3D:
        self.depth = depth
        return self
```

Now I can't do this:

```
cube = M3D().set_width(2).set_height(3).set_depth(5)
```

I get the following error in mypy:

```
_test_typeanotations.py:21: error: "M" has no attribute "set_depth"; maybe "set_width"
```

Because `set_width()` returns an `M` which has no method `set_depth`. I have seen suggestions to override `set_width()` and `set_height()` for every subclass to specify the correct types, but that would be a lot of code to write for each method. There has to be a easier way.

This is also relevant for special methods, for example `__enter__` traditionally returns `self`, so it would be nice to have a way to specify this without needing to even mention it in subclasses.

Comment: Why not make it a classmethod?

Comment: I still use `self` in the method, not only the class

Comment: I believe that's where you'd use Generics and TypeVars, but I haven't used them enough to provide a spontaneous sample.

Comment: The code is wrong anyway, your returns must be in `'` for example `set_width(self, width: int) -> 'M':` as you cannot type the class you are in it without it. Second of all in your calls it should be `box = M().set_width(5).set_height(10)` and lastly, once you fix that the typing works as expected, including the inheritance

Comment: @bluesummers Thank you for pointing out the syntax errors, though the last line of code still has the incorrect types

Comment: About syntax you should add `'` aroudn the class return types as I showed in the last comment. Other than that, in my local environent, there are zero typing problems

Comment: You don't need to, you can simply import `annotations` from `__future__`

Comment: Well, this code has no errors for me and PyCharm highllights everything as working... What is the error yo uare getting?

Comment: I mean, it won't error, but PyCharm won't autocomplete any methods on cube since it can't determine the type of the variable since it thinks the method `set_depth()` doesn't exist

Comment: Without using `annotations` (using the `'`) works fine and autocompletes in PyCharm for me. Could be that PyCharm did not develop this feature yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of research and expirimentation, I have found a way that works in mypy, though Pycham still guesses the type wrong sometimes.

The trick is to make `self` a type var:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import asyncio
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class M:
    def set_width(self: T, width: int)->T:
        self.width = width
        return self

    def set_height(self: T, height: int)->T:
        self.height = height
        return self

    def copy(self)->M:
        return M().set_width(self.width).set_height(self.height)


class M3D(M):
    def set_depth(self: T, depth: int) -> T:
        self.depth = depth
        return self

box = M().set_width(5).set_height(10) # box has correct type
cube = M3D().set_width(2).set_height(3).set_depth(5) # cube has correct type
attemptToTreatBoxAsCube = M3D().copy().set_depth(4) # Mypy gets angry as expected
```

The last line specifically works fine in mypy but pycharm will still autocomplete `set_depth` sometimes even though `.copy()` actually returns an `M` even when called on a `M3D`.

Answer (score 15):

Since Python 3.11, you are able to do this:

```py
from typing import Self

class M:
    def set_width(self, width: int) -> Self:
        self.width = width
        return self
```

Comment: For those on older versions of Python, you can install the `typing-extensions` package and import `Self` like: `from typing_extensions import Self`

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem in any language using inheritance. And it is handled differently by the languages:

- in C++, you would cast the result of `set_height` before calling `set_depth`
- in Java, you could either use the same casting as C++, or have the IDE to generate the bunch of overrides and only manually change the type in the overriden methods.

Python is a dynamically typed language, so there is no cast instruction. So you are left with 3 possible ways:

- the brave way: override all the relevant methods to call the base method and declare the new type in the return annotation
- the *I don't care* way: annotation control only gives warnings. As you know that the line is fine, you can just ignore the warning
- the *don't bother me* way: annotations are optional in Python and annotation control can normally be suspended by special comments. Here **you** know that there is no problem, so you can safely suspend the type control for that instruction or that method.

The following is only my opinion.

I would avoid the *don't bother way* if possible, because if you will leave warnings in your code, you would have to later control after each and every change if there is a new warning.

I would not override methods just to get rid of a warning. After all Python is a dynamically typed language that even allows duck typing. If I know that the code is correct I would avoid adding useless code (DRY and KISS principles)

SO I will just assume that comments to suspend annotation controls were invented for a reason and use them (what I call *don't bother me here*).